# How to bind drop down list with string array in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am able to bind drop down list with a string array by doing so (not sure whether this is the correct way to implement):

```
string[] items = { "111", "222", "333" };
ddlSearch.DataSource = items;
ddlSearch.DataBind();
```

However, what I actually wanted is: When I click the drop down list, the first item showing in the list shall be `111` followed by `222` and `333`.

How am I able to add the strings of text to show in the drop down list when I click the drop down list button?

Java has an easy way to add items to be displayed in the list, but how do we do it in C#? (I am very new to C# by the way.)

Comment: By this way. In what order the items are showing in the dropdown?

Comment: Are you looking to reorder your list? Or are you looking to add additional strings to the list? If you want to add items, it's probably easier to use `List<string>` or `Dictionary<string>`

Comment: I seen several examples of using list, is it possible to populate the drop down list with string array? The order does not matter. For example, I just want "111", "222", "333" in the drop down list.

Comment: So the question is, how to add to the array?

Comment: The question is "how to fill up the drop down list with strings" - preferably array of strings

Comment: Look at Izzy's answer - that should work. My guess is you are including `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` attributes in your listbox - you're only using a string array not key-value pair - so you don't need those.

Comment: Actually what I want is very simple, just to set the values in the dropdownlist. Is it that it can only be done in the `.aspx form`?

Answer (score 11):

It would be easier to use `List<string>`

Markup can be

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The backend code would look like

```
var items = new List<string> {
"111",
"222",
"333"
};
items.Sort(); 

DropDownList1.DataSource = items;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.contexttypename(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class MovieLibrary
{
    string[] _availableGenres = { "Comedy", "Drama", "Romance" };

    public MovieLibrary()
    {
    }

    public string[] AvailableGenres
    {
        get
        {
            return _availableGenres;
        }
    }
}


<asp:LinqDataSource 
    ContextTypeName="MovieLibrary" 
    TableName="AvailableGenres" 
    ID="LinqDataSource1" 
    runat="server">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"
    runat="server" 
    ID="DropDownList1">
</asp:DropDownList>
```