# Trouble binding C# list to DropDownList in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past hour or so because I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this seemingly straight-forward process.

Here is what the ASPX page looks like:

```
<%@ Page Title="Teams" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TeamEntry.aspx.cs" Inherits="Team.Model" Runat="server" Debug="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:DropDownList
            runat="server" 
            ID="DDL_Teams" 
            Width="183px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <input id="Text1" type="text" /><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Team;

namespace Team
{
    public partial class TeamEntry : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) 
            {
                using (var DDL_Teams = new DropDownList())
                {
                    DDL_Teams.DataSource = TeamsList;
                    DDL_Teams.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        List<string> TeamsList = new List<string>()
        {
            "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta"
        };
    }
}
```

...but all I see when I try to run the page is [an empty dropdown list](https://i.imgur.com/7cSoqTJ.png)

I've tried several other approaches noted in other StackOverflow questions related to data binding to dropdown lists (for example, the ones listed on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968600/how-to-bind-drop-down-list-with-string-array-in-asp-net)) to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new dropdown list every time as per this code

```
using (var DDL_Teams = new DropDownList())
```

That's why no binding has occured.

But need to use the dropdown list ID created in HTML.
Please use this code in TeamEntry.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                DDL_Teams.DataSource = TeamsList;
                DDL_Teams.DataBind();

            }


        }
        List<string> TeamsList = new List<string>()
        {
            "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta"
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! However, when I try doing it without the ```using (var DDL_Teams = new DropDownList())```, it throws an error saying that "DDL_Teams does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Dropdownlist on your server side code:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            //using (var DDL_Teams = new DropDownList()) - Comment this line
            {
                DDL_Teams.DataSource = TeamsList;
                DDL_Teams.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

You already have `DDL_Teams` on your web form already. Try to clean your solution and rebuild it.